# Уникализация записей

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица `employee` в PostgreSQL, ее содержимое (часть) ⬇

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно дублирующиеся записи сделать уникальными. Хотела сделать запрос, который будет дописывать `id` в конец `name`

```
UPDATE employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(id) AS id, name, departmetn_id, chief_id, salary FROM employee GROUP BY name, departmetn_id, chief_id, salary) AS tmp
    ON employee.id = tmp.id 
SET employee.name = CONCAT(employee.name, '-', employee.id) 
WHERE tmp.id IS NULL
```

Не работает запрос, выходит ошибка. В чем причина?

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "LEFT")
LINE 23: LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         ^
SQL-состояние: 42601
Символ: 439
```

Отдельно `LEFT OUTER JOIN` работает

Comment: update в таком синтаксисе у postgresql требует фразы from https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/sql-update В вашем случае проще убрать left join вообще а проверку на отсутствие дублей выполнить в where в виде not exists или not in. т.е. `update emploee set ... where id not in(select min(id) from emploee group by ...)`

Comment: *Нужно дублирующиеся записи сделать уникальными.* Переведите эту фразу на русский язык. Ибо все показанные на скриншоте записи - уникальны.

Comment: @Akina c 23 по 26 дублирующиеся

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое! Получилось ```с not (id in ...)``` Такой запрос: UPDATE employee
SET name = CONCAT(name, '-', id) WHERE not (id in (SELECT MIN(id) FROM employee GROUP BY name, departmetn_id, chief_id, salary))

Comment: *c 23 по 26 дублирующиеся* Так у них значение поля `id` различно - какие же это дубли-то? или вы не знаете смысла слова "дубликат"?